# Relationship between Quotient and Remainder vs Modulus and Residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, terminology

I understand the relationship between Modulus (Divisor) and Residue (Congruence Class). But I want to go into the relationship between Quotient and Remainder as these are analogous.

Given a dividend of say... $23$, I can take all integers less than $23$ and treat them as divisors into $23$. Here the result will be a set of quotients and remainders. The relationship between **divisor** and **remainder** is given the nomenclature in mathematics as **modulus** and **residue**. This is shown in the top part of the supplied image below. Notice that the remainders play the role of "Residue" and the divisors play the role of "Modulus". Not is the classical sense, but in the literal.

In the bottom part of the image is a red box around quotients and divisors. Is there a mathematical nomenclature in mathematics that classifies these with different definitions other than "quotients" and "divisors"? More directly, remainder has the alternate name of "Residue", therefore is there an alternate name for quotient?

My Abstract Algebra text discusses Factor Group, Quotient Group and a Quotient Ring, which comes close to an alternate name and definition.

**Why am I asking this question**. Residues have a use in Cryptography and we use the multiplicative inverse pairs to encrypt and decrypt with the same operation with regard to Keys. But I've discovered that the Quotient has a benefit when I perform the $INT(value)$ operation in code to get the integer part. The affect of using just the integer part has an extremely huge benefit in factoring RSA semiprimes when used at the appropriate place in my algorithm. Are there uses in Cryptography of just the integer part... that I'm unaware of and happen just to dumbfound-ly discover it?

[image]

[image]

***Just a note here, the remainders being the same for each operation is not always the case***.

Comment: Residue and remainder are synonyms in this context. There are no similar widely used synonyms for the quotient. The division algorithm (quotient and remainder) is ubiquitous in number theory so it is no surprise that it is used in cryptography. It's not clear what your point is.

Comment: Factor group seems to be a synonym for quotient group, although I think it is not often used. Factor also has a meaning when applied to integers; it means the same as divisor, but only when the division is exact – when the remainder is zero.

Comment: Close this question.